# Poll server to check for updated content

Tags: json, api

I'm programming a json API server. How does the client poll the server to check for new content since the last request? Is the logic in the client or in the server? I've search online for code examples but have only come across conceptual explanations and this makes it very hard for me to understand how the code works. (newbie here)

I'm trying to do this with a timestamp as a param to the request. The timestamp will check the timestamp attached to the content to see if the content was added after the last request was made. Anyway, how is this last request tracked?

Specifically, how do I do this in Go?

Comment: I've edited my questions. Hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Short polling is going to be the simplest route.

Basicly an xhr request in a `setInterval` function.

Nothing special on Go's side.

Your other (more complicated) options are going to be long polling and websockets.